# Bounded Draggable element with details

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm trying to make a div to be draggable and bounded to another container div (light yellow). Using jquery and jquery-UI, i managed to make it work (code pen project [here](https://codepen.io/Bebiuz/pen/xMdNLo) ). Now i'm missing the next step.

I have a (red) button on my draggable header div, which will toggle the visibility of a body div containing some other details. I want also these details to always be shown into my container.

Right now if i drag my (orange) header div on the bottom of its container and open body details (gold) div, it will appear outside container. Is there a way to avoid this, given that i want to have the possibility to drag my header up the bottom of its container? i was thinking to something like

```
if(spaceUnderHeaderDiv < detailsDivHeight) { 
  // make detailsDiv to appear on the top of header instead 
}
```

,so that if i don't have enough space under my header div, i show my body div on the top instead of showing it to the bottom like normally

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You may also like the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I think you want to adjust the `overflow` styling of the container. This way the element is just hidden from view when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you switch to `slide` effect with jQuery UI, you can set the distance. https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped that the `.toggle()` with `slide` and specific options would work.

```
$(".elBody").toggle("slide", {
  direction: "down",
  distance: diff
});
```

Where `diff` was the difference in pixels from the bottom edge of `.elHeader` to the bottom edge of `.container`. This jQuery UI effect works differently than jQuery `.slidetoggle()`.

What I ended up doing was similar, I adjusted the `height` value before issuing `.slideToggle()`.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9q5wt186/13/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function detEdgeDiff(el) {
    var par = el.parent();
    var head = $(".elHeader", el);
    // Calc expected bottom
    var elBottom =  el.position().top + head.height() + 200;
    // Calc bottom edge + Margin of Parent
    var parBottom = par.position().top + par.height() + 20;
    // Default height
    var results = 200;
    if (elBottom > parBottom) {
      var diff = Math.round(elBottom - parBottom);
      results = 200 - diff;
    }
    return results;
  }
  var $element = $(".element");
  $element.draggable({
    containment: ".container",
    handle: ".elHeader"
  });

  $(".expand").on("click", function(e) {
    var d = detEdgeDiff($element);
    $(".elBody").css("height", d + "px").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry for the delay of my answer and thanks for your reply! While it is true that now my .elBody element doesn't overflow, one of the targets i wanted to achieve was that .elBody must be collabsible and ALWAYS visible inside the container. I don't want to hide content, i want to change the way it's displayed to fit to the container. Basically, the final result i would like to achieve, is to drag the whole .element, but to bind to its container only my .elHeader, while the .elBody display must be managed according to .elHeader position

Comment: @Bebiuz the issue is sort of weird, you are using `containement` on the entire element. This keeps parts of the element in the container and does not allow overflow. Basically, you will want to contain some of the element but not all of it. I suspect that a modified `drag` will have to help here.